# Convergence of improper integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Show that

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}ln(x)e^{-x}dx $

converges.

i used integration by parts but it always diverges. any hints?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** Construct a function $g$ that is integrable on $[0,\infty)$ and satisfies $|\log(x) e^{-x}| \le g(x)$. It may be profitable to define $g$ separately on $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $\int_1^{\infty}\ln x\text{e}^{-x}dx$, the following limit is zero:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\ln (x)~\text{e}^{-x}=0$$ so this part converges. Now think of the other part as @Lord noted.

Comment: Nice observation, and hint!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. I am back from the university right now.

Comment: Hello, dear friend!

Comment: @amWhy: Hello Amy. I miss you a lot...

Comment: I miss you to, dear friend! I was hoping to see you last night (for me), before heading to sleep. Today will now be better, having seen you now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We know that the integrals
$$\int_0^1 \log x dx\quad\text{and}\quad \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$$
are convergent.

Now we have
$$\log x e^{-x}\sim_0 \log x\quad\text{and}\quad \log x e^{-x}=_\infty o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
so we can see the convergence of the given integrals.

Comment: Needs an UV! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Break up into two parts, say $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $\infty$. On $(0,1]$, our function has absolute value less than $|\ln x|$. And you can evaluate $\int_0^1 \ln x\,dx$ explicitly. To be formal, you can calculate $\int_c^1 \ln x\,dx$ by parts, and let $c$ approach $0$ from the right.

For the integral from $1$ to $\infty$, note that for large $x$, we have $\ln x\lt e^{x/2}$. We can use for example L'Hospital's Rule to show that $\lim_x\to\infty \frac{\ln x}{e^{x/2}}=0$. In fact, $\ln x\lt e^{x/2}$ for all $x$. So from $1$ to $\infty$, our function is $\lt \frac{e^{x/2}}{e^x}=\frac{1}{e^{x/2}}$.

Comment: Regarding your solution for the $(0,1)$ part, I do not think putting emphasis on explicit primitives is such a good idea in this context. On the contrary, the whole idea of these exercises is to (learn how to) bound crudely the functions to be integrated, usually by comparing them to a member of the scale of power, exponential and logarithm functions, whose integrability is assumed to be known.

Comment: Agree. I did crude on $1$ to $\infty$. For the other, thought about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, and for no good reason opted for explicit (apart from discarding exponential), maybe influenced by OP's mention of parts.